# How can I repaint/update paintComponent immediately?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, repaint

Is there any way that I can immediately update/repaint the screen every time `move()` is called even in nested loops? Because only the `move()` in `actionPerfomed()` is actually updating my screen and repainting it.

```
public void startGame() {


    running = true;
    timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(g);
 }

public void draw(Graphics g) {

    if(running){

    g.fillRect(x, y, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);

    }


 }




public void move()
{
    switch(direction) {
        case 'U':
        y = y - UNIT_SIZE;
        break;
        case 'D':
        y = y + UNIT_SIZE;
        break;
        case 'L':
        x  = x  - UNIT_SIZE;
        break;
        case 'R':
        x  = x  + UNIT_SIZE;
        break;

        // changing coordinates of the graphics should be repainted after this method call
 }


    public void enter( )
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numtiles; i++)
        {
            if (state == 'P' && i != 0)
            {
                while(x != UNIT_SIZE && y != UNIT_SIZE)
                    move();    // this doesn't update the screen //

            }

        move(); // this also doesn't update the screen //

    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       if(running){

            move();   // only this method updates the screen //
            enter();
       }

            repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Are you executing that long-running loop on the event dispatch thread? It looks like you are (because it's called from `actionPerformed`), and that's ***bad***.

Comment: @DavidConrad i'm not though... it's actually my first time using java swing so is it not possible to update/ repaint the screen every time `move` is called then?

Comment: You can call `repaint()` in the `move` method, but if it's called from the UI (say, via a button click, mouse click, mouse motion, etc.) then it is going to run on the event dispatch thread and block repainting the UI unless you use a [SwingWorker's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) [doInBackground](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground()) thread, or your own thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: *is it not possible to update/ repaint the screen every time move is called* Question has already been asked/answered and a working demo provided.. The point of using a Swing Timer is to replace the "while loop". So you start your Timer. In the actionPerformed method you invoke move() and then you check if your stop condition is true. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132413/im-a-beginner-trying-to-add-a-timer-to-a-gui-all-the-solutions-i-have-seen-on/65132526#65132526 for a second example that will stop a Timer

Comment: Post a proper [mre] when asking a question so we don't have to guess what you are doing. The answer in the above link is an example of an "MRE". You can just copy/paste/compile and test.